# How to tune windows 7 for best performance so that it runs on low CPU usage and system Memory?

Tags: windows-7

I was thinking if there is a way such that my pc never have a problem of deadlock. is it possible to warn me if CPU is used more then 90%.

Comment: the problem with monitoring cpu utilization is that it eats a lot of processor...what's usually at the top of taskmgr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following utilities may help you. They are freeware and they work on Windows 7.

### [Process Tamer](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/proctamer/)

> Process Tamer is a tiny (140k) and
>   super efficient utility for Microsoft
>   Windows XP/2K/NT/Vista/Win7 that runs
>   in your system tray and constantly
>   monitors the cpu usage of other
>   processes. When it sees a process that
>   is overloading your cpu, it reduces
>   the priority of that process
>   temporarily, until its cpu usage
>   returns to a reasonable level.

### [Process Lasso](http://www.bitsum.com/prolasso.php)

> Process Lasso is a unique new
>   technology that will improve your PC's
>   responsiveness and stability during
>   periods of high CPU load. Windows, by
>   design, allows programs to monopolize
>   your CPU without restraint -- leading
>   to freezes, hangs, and micro-lags.
>   Process Lasso's ProBalance (Process
>   Balance) technology intelligently
>   adjusts the priorities of running
>   programs so that badly behaved
>   processes won't negatively impact the
>   responsiveness of your PC.